# Scale signal to a given range

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis

Is there a function in MatLab to scale a given signal to a specific range, like how `soundsc` does it with the input?

I have to signals, one is a `wave` file, using `wavreader` (I know one should use `audioreader` now) to load the file, and another file that is being read using `fopen` and `fread`.
Now I want to compare those to signals, but the values of `wavreader` seems to be between -1 and 0, but the other file's signal goes anywhere between -5000 and 0.

Comment: This seems to be a general programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the MATLAB function wavread(), use the 'native' option to specify the output format. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html

That'll give the raw integers.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that there was an option to output the wave file in non-normalized values.

Answer (score 2):

Given the signal $\mathbf{x}$, you can scale the values of $\mathbf{x}$ to fall on the interval $[a,b]$ with

```
x_scaled = (x-min(x))*(b-a)/(max(x)-min(x)) + a;
```

Be aware that this is a very naive scaling, but it is the best you can do without any extra information.  When I say naive, I mean that it assumes that the scaled signal should always have a minimum value of $a$ and a maximum value of $b$.